# any bluetooth keyboards with integrated pointing device (trackball/trackpad)?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, magic-trackpad, remote-control

I'm looking for a keyboard and pointing device which I can use when my laptop is plugged into my TV. It needs to be able to connect to the laptop via bluetooth (I want to minimize the time and effort connecting the laptop), and the pointing device must be integrated into it.

I'm having a big problem finding a device to fit the bill online. I would have thought it was a very popular problem, and that there'd be plenty of devices out there... I've considered buying a bluetooth keyboard and "apple magic trackpad", which would be perfect if they were one unit...

The laptop is a macbook. I don't care if it's designed for windows, so long as it works with OS X.

Recommendations?

Comment: There are many Windows-only items. My guess would be that, without drivers, these would give you keyboard OR mouse (depending on the device) but not both.

Comment: Cheers. That blows chunks if it's true.

Answer (score 1):

The [Logitech diNovo Edge](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/keyboards/keyboard/devices/192) keyboard has a little trackpad on it. It's got a [Mac version](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/434/4429) (~[$150](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=dinovo+edge+mac)).

Also, the [Adesso SlimTouch Wireless Mini Touchpad Keyboard for Mac](http://adesso.com/index.php/en/home/mac-solution/124-wkb-4000mac) (~[$110](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=WKB-4000MAC&hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&prmd=ivns&biw=1920&bih=960&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=4752219177296291081&ei=zPU8Tc-8BI2asAOu642lAw&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CD8Q8wIwAA#ps-sellers)) looks okay. I haven't used this brand, though.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I've read bad reviews of the diNovo's usability: specifically the trackpad. http://reviews.cnet.com/keyboards/logitech-dinovo-edge/4505-3134_7-32098278.html

Comment: The Aldesso one looks cool, but it's not Bluetooth, unfortunately. However, there's a bluetooth one for $129: http://www.adesso.com/en/component/content/article/43-wireless-keyboards/126-wkb-4000bb.html

Answer (score 0):

Fentek has a [mini bluetooth keyboard](http://www.fentek-ind.com/mini_bluetooth.htm) with nubbin which seems to be perfectly suitable, and it's about $50.

There's also an [Aldesso bluetooth mouse-keyboard](http://www.adesso.com/en/component/content/article/43-wireless-keyboards/126-wkb-4000bb.html) for about $130.

Answer (score 0):

If you need rugged solution and price is no object try
https://www.keyboardspecialists.co.uk/Shop/KBS/Product/2992/BT-87-TP/iKeyBT-87-TPDesktopBluetoothKeyboard.aspx